# MySQL - count open items and getting dates from different table

Tags: mysql

Happy Friday All, I have something I can not get sorted. I have asked before for support and found it was the best thing I could do :) So, I want to calculate number of open items based on two dates, open and close. All the data will be counted in t2 and the dates will go from t1 (that stores a lot of dates and hence I use `SELECT DISTINCT`)

So, the tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(

ID int (10),
Date1 date);


insert into T1 values 
( 1, '2018-12-17'),
( 2, '2018-12-18'),
( 3, '2018-12-19'),
( 4, '2018-12-19'),
( 5, '2018-12-19'),
( 6, '2018-12-20'),
( 7, '2018-12-20'),
( 8, '2018-12-21'),
( 9, '2018-12-22'),
(10, '2018-12-23'),
(11, '2018-12-24'),
(12, '2018-12-25'),
(13, '2018-12-26'),
(14, '2018-12-27'),
(15, '2018-12-28');

CREATE TABLE t2
(

ID int (10),
Open_Date date,
Close_Date date);


insert into t2 values 
( 1, '2018-12-17', '2018-12-18'),
( 2, '2018-12-18', '2018-12-18'),
( 3, '2018-12-18', '2018-12-18'),
( 4, '2018-12-19', '2018-12-20'),
( 5, '2018-12-19', '2018-12-21'),
( 6, '2018-12-20', '2018-12-22'),
( 7, '2018-12-20', '2018-12-22'),
( 8, '2018-12-21', '2018-12-25'),
( 9, '2018-12-22', '2018-12-26'),
(10, '2018-12-23', '2018-12-27');
```

This is the outcome I want:

```
+------------+------------+
| Date       | Count_open | 
+------------+------------+
| 17/12/2018 |          1 | 
| 18/12/2018 |          3 | 
| 19/12/2018 |          2 | 
| 20/12/2018 |          3 | 
| 21/12/2018 |          4 | 
| 22/12/2018 |          4 | 
| 23/12/2018 |          3 | 
| 23/12/2018 |          0 | 
| 25/12/2018 |          0 | 
| 27/12/2018 |          0 | 
| 27/12/2018 |          0 | 
| 28/12/2018 |          0 | 
+------------+------------+
```

I have a total black out with the code and need your help.

Comment: `...and hence I use SELECT DISTINCT` I don't see that

Comment: @Strawberry Since the table `t1` has no unique values, a join with `t2` would count rows twice (or more). That's why -- I think -- the `DISTINCT` makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
select
  x.Date1 as 'Date',
  count(distinct t2.id) as 'Count_open'
from (select distinct Date1 from t1) x
left join t2 on x.Date1 between t2.Open_Date and t2.Close_Date
group by x.Date1
order by x.Date1
```

Result:

```
Date        Count_open
----------  ----------
2018-12-17  1                      
2018-12-18  3                      
2018-12-19  2                      
2018-12-20  4                      
2018-12-21  4                      
2018-12-22  4                      
2018-12-23  3                      
2018-12-24  3                      
2018-12-25  3                      
2018-12-26  2                      
2018-12-27  1                      
2018-12-28  0
```

Comment: It throws an error - Unknown column t1.Date1 in field list.

Comment: Fixed. However, I think your expected output is wrong. Isn't it?